# MongoDB create index on date with specific granularity?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

For example, I have a collection with this schema:

```
{
  timestamp: new Date(some-arbitrary-specific-datetime),
  some-other-field: any-type.
}
```

And a common query is to filter and get the documents of a timestamp range:

```
collection.find({
  timestamp: {$lte: someDate, $gte: someLaterDate}
})
```

Performance is important because this collection is large, and the query may return over 100k documents.

In my query, the I'm only interested in the granularity up to the day level.

I wonder if it's possible to create an index on the collection based on the `timestamp`'s day instead of the exact DateTime?

I know that it is possible to do it within the application code, by adding a new field to the collection and create a Date with up to day-level granualarity and query it the same way, i.e.:

```
{
  timestamp: new Date(1476479514),
  date: new Date("2016-10-14"),
  some-other-field: any-type
}
```

and query:

```
collection.find({
  date: {$lte: new Date("2016-10-14"), $gte: new Date("2016-10-12")}
})
```

and create index:

```
collection.collectionName.createIndex({date: 1});
```

but it's not feasible to do it in application code right now. Can I create a similar-performing index using just the `timestamp` field?

Answer (score 0):

I think it will make no difference if you store a date with or without time. In both cases it should be stored internal as a [Date](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#date). Just that the time will be stored as all zeros.

> BSON Date is a 64-bit integer that represents the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970).

So for each comparison on the index or in the collection you server must execute a 64-bit integer comparison, if you add a time to your date or not.

What could make a difference is, that you don't return the whole objects, but with a projection just the fields that you actually want to use and create a composed index, that contains the your timestamp you filter on as first field and all the other fields afterwards. In this way the query can be answered by only accessing the index and the server does not need to load all the objects from disk identified on the index.